# How does this Facebook feed dialog "share" URL use the official FB popup?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-sharer

This appears at the top of the page on an [Upworthy story (for example, here)](http://www.upworthy.com/bill-nye-wasnt-always-the-science-guy-his-story-makes-me-like-him-even-more?c=tpstream) when you scroll down:

[image]

When you click it, you get the official Facebook share dialog popup. So far so good. Now, here is a simplified snippet of the Upworthy HTML code for the button:

```
<a data-url="https://www.facebook.com/dialog/feed?
   app_id=153163221468956
   &display=popup
   &link=URL_TO_SHARE
   &picture=http%3A%2F%2Fsampleimage.jpg
   &redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.upworthy.com%2Ffb-share"
   target="_new" rel="share_popup">

   <span class="text-node"><svg class="icon facebook"><use xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="#ico-facebook"></use></svg><span class="preface">Share on</span> Facebook</span>

</a>
```

They're using a variation of URL version of the [feed dialog feature](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/reference/feed-dialog/v2.2) (*not* the Javascript version), but how do they get the popup to show, instead of just opening a new page? (Also note the link to share isn't even specified; in the Upworthy code on the page, it reads `URL_TO_SHARE` like you see above... what's going on there?!)

Here is the sample code from [Facebook's feed dialog feature](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/reference/feed-dialog/v2.2); notice that it it almost exactly what Upworthy uses, but this will go to a new page (instead of showing the popup). But I want the popup. ;-) How does Upworthy do it?

```
<a href='https://www.facebook.com/dialog/feed?
  app_id=145634995501895
  &display=popup&caption=An%20example%20caption 
  &link=https%3A%2F%2Fdevelopers.facebook.com%2Fdocs%2F
  &redirect_uri=https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer'>

  <img src='http://faculty.orangecoastcollege.edu/sgilbert/book/10-5-ButtonsAndAction-B/images/button.png'>

</a>
```

Comment: The fact that this `a` element does not even have a `href` attribute should make you suspect that they are probably using JavaScript … and the fact that nothing happens any more once you disable JavaScript proves that. `URL_TO_SHARE` is likely used as a simple placeholder that gets replaced by that JavaScript, before it opens a popup with that address …

Comment: Ah yes... are they using a Facebook JS library to do that? I can't find any info about that in the Facebook's docs.